# Facebook Tab Application and PHP Sessions

Tags: php, facebook, session

**Setup:**

There is a Facebook Tab Application (PHP & Javascript), which is installed on two different Facebook Pages. Each instance of the application has some configuration values that differ from the other.

**Problem:**

When the application is loaded through Facebook, I can determine what to load based on Facebook's 'Signed Request'. However, when the application itself makes an AJAX call to update some data for example, is there a way to determine where the call has come from, without sending some kind of identifier with the request?

**Thoughts:**

I tried PHP Sessions and although I'm not very familiar with sessioning, it seems that the application will get confused if both instances are open at the same time. Am I missing something?

I can, of course, send some kind of ID along with each AJAX request to specify where the call is coming from, as mentioned above, but that is something I'd like to avoid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are user-level so it's not the best way to solve your problem.

Instead, the easiest way to solve your problem is to decode `signed_request` and find the `page_id` (part of the `signed_request`). Then, when you make the ajax call on your page, pass the ID in your call (either as `GET` or `POST` data) so your server knows what data to load for that page.

You can do something like:

```
switch ( $_GET['page_id'] ) {
  case '1234':
    // load settings for page 1234
  break;
  case '5678':
    // load settings for page 5678
  break;
}
```

Or you can use a database to manage this more easily and make it scalable.

Comment: So you think there's not another way to do this other than passing an identifier with the ajax call itself, as I've suggested above? My problem is that this has to work for an already existing codebase with hundreds of ajax calls. So if this is the best way, I'd have to replace all the jquery ajax calls with a wrapper that adds that extra ID in the arguments, before making the call, which will be a pain.

Comment: Even if you follow a session based approach using the user's visited page as reference, it will involve the same amount of work. Using a ajax wrapper or changing the base ajax URL would be the easiest way.